# Why are referenced assemblies locked?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, reference

I have 2 assemblies. Assembly2 is referenced by Assembly1. 
Why is Assembly2 locked?

I thought the whole assembly is loaded into the RAM by the JIT-Compiler, isn't it?

How does the machinism work when a referenced assembly is called?

Comment: Because there might be some process which is *locking* them. What kind of a question is this? Do you really expect some useful answers?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov; if they asked the question, maybe they hoped for a useful answer?  Maybe tell them *why* it's a bad question.  :-)

Comment: Got more information about your question, witch assembly is locked when, why is it a problem?

Comment: @Dean J, I thought that it is pretty obvious that when you expect useful answers you first describe some scenario, what you are trying to achieve, what you've tried to achieve this goal, what didn't work, what were the expected/actual results, etc... none of which is currently present in this question.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov; then tell them that.  They're still <500 reputation, and probably fairly new to C#.  Instead of telling them passive aggressively that they've asked a stupid question, try a little to help, maybe?  Note that Assaf Lavie managed a decent answer to the problem.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, yes I am expecting useful answers :o

Comment: @Dean J, +1 from me, well said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(yes, the question could have been better, still...)

Referenced assemblies are loaded into the process and are thus locked. You can get around this with shadow copying, or just make sure you close every process that uses your assemblies before you attempt to modify them.

Comment: I thought the whole assembly is in the RAM, isn't it?

Comment: @Rookian That's a great question. I wonder if the whole assembly gets loaded into memory or just the parts needed to be referenced by other applications, i.e. the parts marked `public`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a situation when writing a .NET componenet to be consumed in a VB6 app where I couldn't deploy my recompiled .NET assembly while the VB6 editor was open.  This really frustrated me because I wanted to be able to just make a quick change and then have the change show up in my VB6 editor.  I was getting an error message that the assembly was locked by another process or thread.

I later realized that this made a lot of sense.  If the referencing application (in my case, the VB6 IDE) is trusting that library to be the same each time it goes to consume it, it's going to run into serious problems if the dll changes while the application is in memory.

In my case, closing the VB6 IDE, updating the dll, and reopening the VB6 IDE worked just fine.  It was a little bit of a hindrance in my workflow, but once I realized why it was happening, I got over it.